# What's the difference between these two regexes: (0+1)* vs (01)*

Tags: regex

Please describe the difference between `(0+1)*` and `(01)*`, and between `(0+1)+` and `(01)+`, with examples.

`(0+1)+` means a non empty string of (0+1) similarly for (01)+.

Comment: which language you use or regex style?

Comment: The first matches zero or more instances of one or more zeros followed by a one, capturing the last instance. The latter matches zero or more instance of `01`, capturing the last instance. I'll leave the second pair as an exercise to you. Please do some research on regexen, since this is very basic stuff. I'd recommend starting [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: So, "Please do [my] homework for me?"

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. Am a beginner, got confused, thus raised in SO.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation all around the world, please do not expect to be taught, be able to learn yourself. With respect to other people time especially, as majority learn themself by just googling things as there is huge amount of data on those topics.
Do not expect to understand things via shortcuts - it does not work.

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research.

Answer (score 2):

```
(0+1)*
```

- Means sequences of one-or-more 0 followed by a 1.
- Matches `01`, `0001`, `0101`.
- Matches a empty string.
- Doesn't match `1`, `0`, `101`, `011`, `010`.

```
(01)*
```

- Means sequences of "01".
- Matches `010101`
- Matches a empty string.
- Doesn't match, `1`, `0`, `010`.

```
(0+1)+ and (01)+
```

Are equivalent to the others, except that they require at least one match.  Thus, they will not match an empty string.

Note that these expressions in some languages don't require that to be the entire string.  Some functions implicitly add `^` to the start, and `$` to the end.  Most often, they won't do this, so these would match `foo 0101 bar`.

Comment: by (0+1)^+, I meant (0+1)+ i.e there shouldn't be any empty string unlike (0*). similarly  (01)^+ == (01)+

Comment: Okay, I corrected my answer to include this.  Please update your question as well.

Comment: @ FakeRainBrigand: But (01)* is similar to (0*1*) as L(r*) = L(r)* where L(r) denotes language of any regular expression. thus (01)* is similar to (0*1*) . Therefore, it accepts strings such as: 0000,111,000111,0111. pls clarify..

Comment: `*` means 0 or more of the item before it.  If it doesn't have any modifier, it means exactly 1.  In math `0*` means `[0, inf)` 0s and `0` means `[1,1]` 0s.  `(01)*` would not match anything that isn't a number of "01" repetitions.  It matches "", "01", "0101", "01010101", etc.

Comment: (01)* is nothing like (0*1*). The latter is just zero or more 0s followed by zero or more 1s, and never a 0 after a 1.